# Is this communication I²C?

Tags: i2c, communication

I need to decode communication between two devices, but I have no information about these devices. All I know is that four wires are needed (GND, VCC and two wires of communication). I suspect that it is I²C communication.

I'm trying to decode it with the oscilloscope decoding tool, but I'm not quite sure about it. I can not identify elements of I²C communication appropriately when I visually check the waveforms.

Looking at the waveforms I made the following assumptions, and maybe someone can help. These were my assumptions:

1. Everything leads to believe that the clock is the blue signal and the data is the red signal.
2. The clock seems to be inverted because its idle state is not at high level.
3. I'm not sure if the data signal is also inverted, but it seems to be.

Are my assumptions correct?

In the last figure, the figure with the number 5 indicated in a circle, and there is a part of the signal. I can not identify the start, ack and stop bits. Can anyone identify these elements just looking at the figure?

[image]
[image]

[Edited] Some people asked me about the devices that are in the communication. The communication is between a car key and a tool that I'm not allowed to say, but I'm trying to do a reverse engineering on it.

Comment: You have the start condition at the leftmost red (SDA) edge. It goes low while inverted blue (–SCL) is held low. After that, changes to red (SDA) seem to occur only when the inverted blue (–SCL) is high. That's valid I²C talk.

Comment: @Janka, that's only valid I2C talk if you assume that SCL is inverted. There's no reason to assume that.

Comment: The OP wrote exactly that.

Comment: @Janka, the OP listed that as an assumption. That assumption is based on the assumption that this is I2C. There are several reasons to believe this is not I2C--one of them being that the clock is idle low.

Comment: Where that assumption came from? On (1) and (2) both lines are high at the very beginning, and on (1) they also high at the end

Comment: @Daniel, would you be able to tell us what the two devices are?

Comment: True I2C uses pull-up resistors and open-drain pins.  But maybe there's an I2C variant that doesn't?  It should be easy to check your setup, whatever it is, for pull up resistors, but the rising edges look too clean (no time constant).

Comment: i think some hints about the content of the communication would help -- do you have any reason to assume bidirectionality?

Comment: @Annie , this communication is between a tool and a circuit of a car's imobilizer key

Comment: Perhaps instead of worrying about "what it is" you should think about "what it says".   Figure out which edge(s) you need to sample.  Get a logic analyzer, probably the streaming USB kind, and start writing a decoder which captures the scope of variability.  Then start seeking patterns in the data.

Comment: @ChrisStratton It seem to be a good idea, however,  I don't have a  logic analyzer available for now

Comment: @RobStarling  I really don't know if it would require bidirectionality, but I guess it is needed because the tool returns the status, success or error of the procedure.

Comment: If you're serious about this project, you're going to need to buy a basic sigrok-compatible logic analyzer ($12 or so), or spend inordinately more time building a custom one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess is that it's some company's homegrown "I2C-like" protocol. There were some of those back in the day when using I2C meant having to give money to Philips.

It appears to have an ACK (the short pulse on the data line prior to the clock stretch looks a lot like the data line getting passed from master to slave).

Oddly, it appears to transmit 7 bits at a time.

Comment: If it is proprietary version of the protocol it might use 7 or less bit communication just as well

Comment: @Maple Yeah. I can picture an engineer saying, "How do we make this like I2C but just enough different that we don't have to pay royalties? Invert the clock and send 7 bits at a time." But I can only guess.

Answer (score 11):

Given that there are only 8 clocks per byte (I2C requires a 9th clock for the ACK/NAK bit) and the clock idle state seems to be low, I would say that this is more likely a SPI (or SPI-like) interface.

Not sure about the extra clock width on the first bit of each byte, however.

Comment: On the other hand, that narrow pulse at the end of clock sequence looks a lot like NACK. Also what looks like idle low could be clock stretching, which is no longer allowed by spec but could be used by old slaves. The initial state on pictures (1) and (2) is actually high

Comment: @Maple: I see your narrow data pulse, but I still fail to see the 9th clock pulse. The data pattern is perfectly consistent with certain SPI configurations of clock phase and clock polarity.

Comment: That is true, I actually agree with you re clock. What is strange to me is inconsistent SDI/SDO (whatever it is) idle behavior at the ends of (1)

Comment: @Maple Wouldn't I2C release the lines to idle high?

Comment: @Selvek Yes, and that is exactly what I see on picture (1) and beginning of picture (2). The rest of it, however, more consistent with SPI, as Dave pointed out. Well, aside from surprising first clock that looks like start bit. Hmm... start bit... could this be...

Comment: @Selvek  Yup, I2C has both lines high when bus is idle.  The waveforms in question don't look like I2C.

Answer (score 3):

I'll toss my hat into the ring...

If these are old devices you could be looking at some "bare minimum" 7-bit synchronous RS-232 variant:

- That longer pulse in the beginning of each frame could be a start bit, and
- The plateau in the clock signal at the very beginning could be return to 0 before going to negative "mark". (You did not provide voltage on screenshots, so I am guessing here).

Comment: Oooh, this is new to me. Does it have any ack? (Couldn't find one in my very brief Google search). If not, anything else that would explain the short pulse on the data line after the 8th clk?

Comment: Not that I know of. And in any case, if this is indeed an old-fashioned serial, any communication in other direction would require separate wires. That pulse is too short to be anything significant. Most likely the driver resetting itself before next frame. All this is guessing, as you said yourself. Unless OP provides more details on the devices this is all we can do.

Comment: @Maple , the communication is between a car key and a tool that I'm not allowed to say, but I'm trying to do reverse engineering on it.

Comment: RS232 is a standard for electrical levels, not for encoding data words

Comment: @ChrisStratton Where did you find anything about encoding in my answer? All I am saying is that if the voltage levels correspond to RS232 and signals resemble synchronous serial then it most likely is not I2C

Comment: The voltage levels are unlikely to be anything like RS232.  Do you remember what RS232 levels are?  Because it sounds a lot more like you are typing RS232, but meaning "a logic level UART leaking a clock or a USART perhaps operating in synchronous mode"... which is *not* what RS232 means.

Comment: "logic level UART"? Please, read my answer again. I specifically mention plateau in the very beginning and what looks like signal going _negative_ after idling at 0 for a shot period. And I specifically mention voltages missing on screenshots. How can they be "unlikely" if they are missing altogether?!

Comment: There are at least three reasons why that's extraordinarily unlikely.  First, RS232 levels would not be found in a keyfob.  Second, the poster would have said something about such unusual (for such a purpose) voltage levels.  Third a midpoint voltage is not characteristic of RS232.

Comment: Note, that the answer was posted _before_ OP mentioned keyfob. Even then it was clearly marked as just a guess based on insufficient data. With that additional bit of information it looks more likely to be some proprietary synchronous serial communication, which makes all guesses made so far incorrect and also irrelevant, as you said so yourself in the comment to OP

Answer (score -1):

According to my experience with I2C, I can use multi-meter device to check the clock by setting the device to measure the frequency (in hertz), so if it reads a steady value like 2k then it is I2C clock.

Comment: No, that's not a valid conclusion at all.  Many things that are not I2C have steady clocks.  In fact, I2C *does not* have a steady clock, but rather a bursty one.  If your meter is counting over a period of time, it's actually going to be averaging active clocking with idle interludes - you'd need to measure the reciprocal of the width of a pulse, ideally on a scope where you can be sure that you are actually measuring what is intended.   In contrast, some other schemes like I2S tend to have continuously running clocks.   But clock frequency can only rule something out, not in.